# dispatch in axios interceptor with redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to dispatch a redux toolkit action inside an axios response interceptor.

I've seen some other question suggesting people to use `store.dispatch(somefunction())`

In redux toolkit you usually call the `useDispatch()` hook to dispatch an action, but since its a hook I can't call it inside of my non-component axios intercept function.

myaxios.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080'
export const myaxios = axios.create({
  baseUrl: BASE_URL
})
```

axiosWithIntercept.js (shortened to scope of question):

```
import { myaxios } from './myaxios'
myaxios.interceptors.response.use(resp => resp, async (err) => {
  if (err?.resp?.status === 401) {
    // run my dispatch action here
  }
})
export default myaxios
```

Comment: What have you tried? Importing the store object and using `store.dispatch` seems perfectly fine to me. Is there some issue in any implementation that you've tried?

Comment: redux-toolkit doesn't have a generic store module you can import. You need to use the  `useDispatch()` hook. And b/c its a hook I can't use it in a normal function that isn't a component. The solution Sahab provided seems to be the most viable way, but I want to wait and see what other ideas people have.

Comment: You import the store you created, e.g. the same store the app is using. No, Sahab's suggestion is a bit convoluted (*and silly*) and unnecessary. What I'm suggesting is the same as @Vivekajee's answer. An alternative is to refactor the code so you can add the axios interceptors from a `useEffect` hook where the `useDispatch` hook is also in scope and usable. Do either of these suggestions make sense?

Comment: You're right, directly importing the store seems to be working. Wasn't aware this was possible since I've always just been told to utilize `useDispatch`. There seems to be a lot of discussion around directly importing store into a component to be an anti-pattern, but since this isn't a component I think it should be fine.

Comment: Correct. In a React component you'd use `useSelector` to subscribe the component to specific state changes, and use `useDispatch` to access the provided store's `dispatch` function. When outside React however, these obviously fall flat, so using the `store` object directly is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use in this way too.

```
import store from './path-to-your-redux-store'; // Update the path accordingly
.
.
.
myaxios.interceptors.response.use(resp => resp, async (err) => {
  if (err?.response?.status === 401) {
    // Dispatch your Redux action here
    store.dispatch(yourReduxAction());
  }
  return Promise.reject(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { myaxios } from './myaxios';

export const myaxiosFunc = (dispatch,storeActions) => {
    myaxios.interceptors.response.use(resp => resp, async (err) => {
        if (err?.resp?.status === 401) {
            // run my dispatch action here
            dispatch(storeActions.yourMethodName());
        }
    })

}

export default myaxiosFunc;
```

Comment: Wouldn't be able to use `useDispatch()` here because this file/function isn't a function component. I would ideally like to keep it this way b/c I need to use `myaxios` inside of other non-component functions such as `createAsyncThunk`

Comment: @jjyj  i have updated my answer , you can pass dispatch and storeActions from a  function component.